# bad CPU type in executable: wine @ macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, mac, wine, macos-catalina

My [`wine`](http://winehq.org/) met some problems while executing Windows executable file:

```bsh
$ wine GECacheBldr.exe
zsh: bad CPU type in executable: wine
```

How to fix this?

PS: My wine is installed using HomeBrew:

```bsh
$ brew cask install wine-stable
```

**EDIT**

Cannot execute `winecfg` either:

```bsh
$ winecfg
/usr/local/bin/winecfg: line 46: /usr/local/bin/wine: Bad CPU type in executable
/usr/local/bin/winecfg: line 46: /usr/local/bin/wine: Undefined error: 0
```

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408375/zsh-bad-cpu-type-in-executable rosetta stone manual install fixed it for me.

Comment: @dcsan It happens on x86_64 machines with wine, not Rosetta-related.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try

```
file `which wine`
```

If it says something in the lines of `Mach-O executable i386`: Apple dropped support for 32bit executables with Catalina 10.15.

You might want to try `wine64` instead of `wine`.

Comment: How to run a 32-bit Windows executable file? Or I can never use them?

Comment: Alas, not with `wine` on Catalina 10.15 any more. You could use a virtual machine (like VirtualBox - it's free), but then you would need a Windows license, and have to install Windows inside the VM.

Comment: I don't think this accepted solution actually solves the problem.

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś there is no solution insofar one cannot use 32bit software on MacOS Catalina. Either use 64bit wine or downgrade MacOS, or try a different approach (like VirtualBox), see above.

Comment: Is there a reason that the Wine devs don't just make the `wine` command launch 64-bit Wine?

Comment: @AaronFranke In my opinion, not really. I guess the developers could (a) replace `wine` with a shell script (to launch either wine32 or wine64 depending on `arch`), (b) create a symlink at install time, or even (c) make it an [universal binary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/building-a-universal-macos-binary). Perhaps someone will do that one day.

Answer (score 2):

I did

```
rm /usr/local/bin/wine
```

then

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/wine64 /usr/local/bin/wine
```

because "wine" is the 32bit version which is tried first by all scripts and apparently OS X does not provide a compatibility layer for 32bit.

It basically works but so far I wasn't able to do everything I need, I still got errors when executing some wine related commands.

Another options I tried with more success in prepending `WINE=/usr/local/bin/wine64`
before every wine related commands I want to run, including winetricks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/wine64 /opt/homebrew/bin/wine` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Been having the same issue, for 13.4.1 Ventura.

The answer from Иван Балдин should have worked but they added a second line.

```
if [ -x "$WINELOADER" ]; then exec "$WINELOADER" "$appname" "$@"; fi
...
if [ -x "$appdir/wine" ]; then exec "$appdir/wine" "$appname" "$@"; fi
```

Comment out these 2 lines and winecfg should work.

Answer (score 0):

try to edit winecfg file, comment this line

```
if [ -x "$appdir/wine" ]; then exec "$appdir/wine" "$appname" "$@"; fi
```

it should  look like that

```
#if [ -x "$appdir/wine" ]; then exec "$appdir/wine" "$appname" "$@"; fi
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).